# Nosetests gives ImportError when __init__.py is included (using cython)

Tags: python-3.x, compiler-errors, cython, nose, nosetests

I just came across a very strange error while using nose and cython inside my virtualenv with python3. For some reason nosetests started giving me an ImportError even though `python -m unittest basic_test.py` was working. I made a new directory to reproduce the error to make sure there wasn't something weird in that directory.

Here are the three files: fileA.pyx, setup.py, and basic_test.py

```
file1.pyx
class FileA:
    def __init__(self):
        self.temp = {}
```

setup.py:

```
from distutils.core import setup
from distutils.extension import Extension
from Cython.Distutils import build_ext

ext_modules = [
    Extension('fileA', ['fileA.pyx'],)
]
setup(
    name='test',
    ext_modules=ext_modules,
    cmdclass={'build_ext': build_ext},
)
```

basic_test.py:

```
def test():
        from fileA import FileA
        FileA()
        assert True
```

Fresh directory. I run `python setup.py build_ext --inplace`. It compiles. I run `nosetests` the single test passes.

Then I do `touch __init__.py` and then run `nosetests` again and it fails with this error:

```
ImportError: No module named 'fileA'
```

Is this a bug or do I not understand how **init** affects imports?

Update:
I found this [post](http://python-notes.curiousefficiency.org/en/latest/python_concepts/import_traps.html) about import traps and read something that might explain how adding **init** breaks it. I still don't get exactly how it fits in though.

> This is an all new trap added in Python 3.3 as a consequence of fixing
>   the previous trap: if a subdirectory encountered on sys.path as part
>   of a package import contains an **init**.py file, then the Python
>   interpreter will create a single directory package containing only
>   modules from that directory, rather than finding all appropriately
>   named subdirectories as described in the previous section.